# Opencv object detection in a circular area in C++

Tags: c++, c, image, opencv, image-processing

I am a newbee in opencv and I need to detect an object in a circular area.I have an image and i have a fixed point in the image.

Taking the point as the centre of the circle, I need to detect the object in the circle with diameter d.So i think firstly i have to cut the circular part and detect the object in it.How can i do this?

PSEUDO CODE:

```
 void detect_func() {    

 IpImage im= cvLoadImage(my_image);

 Cut_The_Circular_Area();

 Detect_Object();
}
```

Comment: You can create a mask using circle and copy source to new image along with  the mask. And if your a newbee don’t use deprecated C,  start with C++

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat image = imwrite("lena.jpg");
Mat roi = cvCreateMat( image.rows,image.cols, CV_8UC1 );
Mat test = cvCreateMat( image.rows,image.cols, CV_8UC1 );
for( int i=0; i < res.cols; i++ )
    for( int j=0; j < res.rows; j++ )
         roi.at<uchar>(Point(i,j)) = 0;
circle( roi, point, radius, 255, -1, 8, 0 );
image.copyTo( test,roi );
for( int i=0; i < test.cols; i++ )
     for( int j=0; j < test.rows; j++ )
         if( test.at<uchar>(Point(i,j)) > 0) {
             //Do your processing here
         }
```

I guess this could help you, even I didnt know that, we cant crop a circular ROI just like a normal Rect, so I tried this snippet, it might work for you